# Saving The scraped contents to Sqllite3 database- How to?

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have trying to scrape a website say Stackoverflow. I have written a code which scrapes the text as well as the images and the urls. I want to save this data to sqllite database.

I've already made a connection to the database..However I am getting an error while saving the contents to the database.

here's my code
scraper.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import sqlite3
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')
soup.prettify()
text_data = soup.find_all('p')
print(text_data) #This will return all Text data.
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href')) #This will return all urls

html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
for image in images:
    print(image['src']+'\n') #This will return all Image urls

conn  = sqlite3.connect('scraped.sqlite3',check_same_thread=False)
curs = conn.cursor()
#curs.execute("INSERT INTO scraped(data,link,img_url) values('text_data','link.get('href')','image['src']")
conn.commit()
```

after entering this line into the program

````
curs.execute("INSERT INTO scraped(data,link,img_url) values('text_data','link.get('href')','image['src']")
``` it throws an error like sqlite3.OperationalError: near "href": syntax error
I tried finding it but didnt understand it. Sorry if it is something very trivial
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
curs.execute(
    "INSERT INTO scraped (data, link, img_url) "
    "VALUES ('{text_data}', '{href}', '{image}'".format(
        text_data=text_data,
        href=link.get('href'),
        image=','.join([image['src'] for image in images])
    )
)
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

---

NOTE. Thanks to @Shawn, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58408176/6266737), always be aware of SQL-injection

Comment: Should be using parameters, not inserting values directly in a query string.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using parameters in your query and binding the values you want to insert to them, which avoids all sorts of nastiness caused by unbalanced quotes in the values to be inserted, etc. Look up *sql injection* for more:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO scraped(data,link,img_url) VALUES (?,?,?)", (text_data, link.get('href'), image['src']))
```